# How to add fruit to array java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have to write two methods for a Fruit program that involves arrays. One of them is `public void addFruit(String other)` and the other is `public void deleteFruit(String del)`. I have already done the `deleteFruit`.

How do I do the addFruit?

I don't what the code is or how to code it.

```
public class Fruit {

private String[] bowl;

public Fruit()
{
    bowl = new String[10];
    bowl[0] = "apple";
    bowl[1] = "banana";
    bowl[2] = "kiwi";
    bowl[3] = "lemon";
    bowl[4] = "lime";
    bowl[5] = "mango";
    bowl[6] = "orange";
    bowl[7] = "pear";
    bowl[8] = "pineapple";
    bowl[9] = "plum";
}



public Fruit(int x)
{
    bowl = new String[] {"apple", "banana", "lemon", "lime", "mango"};
}


public void display()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < bowl.length; x++)
        System.out.println(bowl[x]);
}

public void deleteFruit(String del)
{
    int index = -1;
    for(int i=0; i< bowl.length; i++)
        if (bowl[i].equals(del))
            index = i;
    if (index ==-1)
        System.out.println("Not in the list");
    else
    {
        for (int i = index; i< bowl.length -1; i++)
            bowl[i] = bowl [i+1];
        String[] temp = new String[bowl.length-1];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
            temp[i]= bowl [i];
        bowl = temp;
        System.out.println("item deleted");
    }
public void addFruit(String other)
{

}
}
```

Comment: Your program need `List<String> bowl=new  ArrayList<String>();` instead of `String[]`. as string[] not allow you to add more than size 5.

Comment: If they don't have to be void, you could return a new array one longer than Bowl (or a Bowl class with an array property??) with all the data copied, and then stick the other one at the end.

Comment: Assuming the array length is not fixed, you will need, once you've determined that there are no free spaces, create a new array which is 1 element larger then the current array, copy the contents from the current array to the new array and add the new item to the end

Comment: You cant change array size runtime, so you need to use `List`, then you can add new data in Fruit.

Comment: As a good general rule, *never* use arrays useless you absolutely have to

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most effective solution, but it works.

```
public void addFruit(String other) {
    String[] res = new String[bowl.length + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < bowl.length; i++) {
        res[i] = bowl[i];
    }
    res[res.length - 1] = other;
    bowl = res;
}
```